# Pygame Image Not Moving

Tags: python, pygame

Okay so I've just started on a pygame program. And the image is not moving? I'm like 99% sure I did everything right... I'm probably making a stupid mistake though. Here's the code.

```
import pygame

pygame.init()

white = (255,255,255)
black = (0,0,0)


window_width = 800
window_height = 600

gameDisplay = pygame.display.set_mode((800,600))
clock = pygame.time.Clock()




def gameLoop():

    while True:
    characterimg = pygame.image.load('racecar.png')
    characterx = 500
    charactery = 500


    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            False
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                characterx += -10
                charactery += 0
            if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                characterx += 10
                charactery += 0
            if event.key == pygame.K_UP:
                charactery += -10
                characterx += 0
            if event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
                charactery += 10
                characterx += 0



        gameDisplay.fill(white)           
        gameDisplay.blit(characterimg, (characterx,charactery))
        pygame.display.update()
        clock.tick(15)




gameLoop()
pygame.quit
quit()
```

If you could please help me I would appreciate it very much. Please tell me what I'm doing wrong :)

Comment: your code has wrong indentions - or you have to use button `{}` to correctly format code on SO.

Comment: BTW: you forgot `()` in `pygame.quit()`

Comment: Fixed it. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your mistake is here

```
while True:
    characterimg = pygame.image.load('racecar.png')
    characterx = 500
    charactery = 500
    # ... code ...
```

In every loop you move image back to position `(500, 500)`.

You have to do it before `while True`

```
characterimg = pygame.image.load('racecar.png')
characterx = 500
charactery = 500

while True:
    # ... code ...
```

---

My version:

```
import pygame

# --- constants --- (UPPER_CASE_NAMES)

WHITE = (255, 255, 255)
BLACK = (0, 0, 0)

WINDOW_WIDTH = 800
WINDOW_HEIGHT = 600

# --- classes --- (CamelCaseNames)

# empty

# --- functions --- (lower_case_names)

# empty

# --- main --- (lower_case_names)

# - init -

pygame.init()
display = pygame.display.set_mode((WINDOW_WIDTH, WINDOW_HEIGHT))

# - objects -

character_image = pygame.image.load('racecar.png')
character_x = 500
character_y = 500

# - mainloop -

clock = pygame.time.Clock()
running = True

while running:

    # - events -

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False
        elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                character_x -= 10
            elif event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                character_x += 10
            elif event.key == pygame.K_UP:
                character_y -= 10
            elif event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
                character_y += 10

    # - updates -

    # empty

    # - draws -

    display.fill(WHITE)           
    display.blit(character_image, (character_x, character_y))
    pygame.display.update()

    # - FPS -

    clock.tick(15)

# - end -

pygame.quit()
```

Comment: Once again you have helped me so much. I honestly can't thank you enough. The world needs more people like you :)

Comment: I put full version with less important changes.